# Class not found when using a package with Netbeans/Composer

Tags: php, netbeans, composer-php, wamp, phpspreadsheet

I'am using NetBeans IDE 8.2, I created a PHP application and using the composer within the IDE, I installed a package "phpspreadsheet" :

[image]

The package is then installed in the vendor folder and I even have the autocompletion when using the package's classes.

[image]

But when I run this project, it's throws me this error :

**Fatal error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory' not found in C:\wamp64\www\NetBeansComposer\index.php on line 5**

Is it beacause WAMP can't access the vendor folder? How can I fix this?

Comment: I tried using another package just in case but I still got the same error when I load classes of a package installed with composer.

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

resolved the problem for me.